# how to do custom animation in a mhx file made using Makehuman

Tags: animation, makehuman

I have a human model made using Makehuman tool. I have exported it to Blender. **As a beginner** I found it very confusing. Could see lots of details.

Looking for some simple tutorial that helps learning animation from this file. I need to do animation of hand,face.

This is for academic research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read or watch a few of the available [tutorials](http://www.makehuman.org/documentation) or [100 'best'](http://meta-guide.com/videography/100-best-makehuman-videos/), the mhx addon adds buttons for the rig-layers where you can select which manipulators are shown in the viewport.
The following animation was recorded in *Pose Mode*. You should read about the difference between IK/FK.
After that just record your animation by keyframing the poses setup by the controls.

[image]