# Blender animation using MakeHuman files

Tags: animation, rigging, makehuman

My objective is to have a room in which a person is doing some activities like bending, walking, etc. I am using MakeHuman to model the person. After that, in blender I import the model from make human. Now, I need some help on how to make an animation like walking. Does MakeHuman use armatures?

Comment: You can use armatures on meshes generated from MakeHuman and imported into Blender. This is not strictly on topic, you might want to look for some rigging/animating tutorials online as this process is generally fairly complex and there are many different ways to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different rig-types available *rigify* and *mhx* you need to enable the corresponding addon in the *User Preferences*.

MakeHuman rig (mhx)

[image]

Rigify
[image]

The bones are organized in layers, with the addon enabled you get buttons to select them, in *Pose Mode* you can setup poses and keyframe them.

[image]

Same for rigify:
[image]

Related:

- [How should an animated character be moved while repeating a walk cycle?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/how-should-an-animated-character-be-moved-while-repeating-a-walk-cycle/3740#3740)
- [What are the not so obvious features of Rigify?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/what-are-the-not-so-obvious-features-of-rigify/1856#1856)
- [how to do custom animation in a mhx file made using Makehuman](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16246/how-to-do-custom-animation-in-a-mhx-file-made-using-makehuman/16254#16254)

Comment: I know just mhx and I already used it in blender without any problem. But what is the difference between rigify and mhx in manipulation?

Comment: @startingBlender both are comparable.If you created the model with makehuman then using mhx should be fine. Personally I use rigify only for characters I created myself by modelling. Regarding the part of your question "Does MakeHuman use armatures?" Yes, the manipulators you see are custom shapes, the actual bones hidden on separate layers and many of them are controlled by drivers.

Comment: good. What does mean by characters? It means a detailed gestures like eyes gestures, fingers gestures,...